# Forking and pipes: does this C program contain a race condition?

Tags: c, process, pipe, fork, parent-child

I'm learning about interprocess communication and came across the below example program.

I don't understand what's to prevent the parent process from attempting the *read* (as part of the else condition at the bottom of the program) before the child process has completed the *write*.

What (if anything) constrains the parent process from attempting the read from standard input before the child process has written to standard output?

```
int main(void)
{
    int     fd[2], nbytes;
    pid_t   childpid;
    char    string[] = "Hello, world!\n";
    char    readbuffer[80];

    pipe(fd);

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
            /* Child process closes up input side of pipe */
            close(fd[0]);

            /* Send "string" through the output side of pipe */
            write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));
            exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
            /* Parent process closes up output side of pipe */
            close(fd[1]);

            /* Read in a string from the pipe */
            nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
            printf("Received string: %s", readbuffer);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: when calling the system function 'pipe()', always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  on success, pipe() returns 0 on failure, pipe() returns -1 and sets 'errno'

Comment: the comments about the closing of the pipe ends are backwards

Comment: the 'read()' function does not append a string terminator byte '\0' to the read string, so the immediate call to printf() (probably) will fail.  Depending on which happens first, the read() or the write(), the read may return without having read all the data bytes.   The read should be in a loop, while checking/accumulating the returned byte counts.  When the returned byte count is 0 then terminate the string, using the accumulated byte counts,  (might not be necessary since child sends a termination byte, but is good practice) If the returned value is ever < 0 handle the error

Comment: @user3629249: the `read()` call will read the null byte that the `write()` call includes in the data sent on the pipe.  The length written is `strlen() + 1` to include the null byte.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents the parent from starting the `read()` call before the child has written anything to the pipe, but the parent process won't get any data until after the child has written data to the pipe (and that write will be atomic because it is less than the length of the pipe buffer).  The parent will hang waiting for either some data to arrive on the pipe or every writing end of the pipe to be closed.

Note that if `nbytes == 0` after the read, the output from `printf()` is indeterminate because `readbuffer` is not initialized.

Comment: Thanks - this leads me to another question, which probably stems from another misunderstanding on my part but I'll ask anyway -  how does the parent know when there is no more data coming into the pipe buffer? I am thinking of the scenario where the parent starts the read, and the child then writes the "H" of "Hello, world!" - what's to prevent the parent from assuming immediately after it has read the "H" that there is nothing left to read?

Comment: The reading process gets 0 bytes returned when there is no more data to read and there is no process that could write more data (so all the write ends of the pipe are closed).  The kernel handles that; the reading process only has to pay attention to the value returned by the `read()` function.

Comment: @sav0h As long as one or more processes have the pipe's write channel open, the reading process (in your code, the parent) will always assume that there is something else to read (and will block in `read(2)` if there's nothing available at the moment). Note that *Hello, world!* is smaller than `PIPE_BUF`, so the write is atomic (see `man 7 pipe`); assuming the buffer passed to `read(2)` is long enough, one `read(2)` call is enough.